# Infinispan cluster error: MarshallableUserObject marshaller not overridden in SerializationContext

Tags: infinispan

I have a test cluster with 2 embedded nodes (Infinispan 12.1.4.Final). I use a replicated cache with RocksDB cache-store. The cache's size is about 4 GB. And sometimes, when I restart nodes, I get that exception, and one of the nodes freezes - it waits for cache rebalance. The replicated cache's configurated like:

```xml
    <replicated-cache name="event" statistics="true">
            <expiration interval="3600000"/>
            <persistence>
                <rocksdb-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:rocksdb:12.1" path="rocksdb/data" fetch-state="true">
                    <expiration path="rocksdb/expired"/>
                </rocksdb-store>
            </persistence>
            <memory max-count="100"/>
            <indexing>
                <index-reader refresh-interval="5000"/>
                <indexed-entities>
                    <indexed-entity>org.example.model.IndexedEndpointEventModel</indexed-entity>
                </indexed-entities>
            </indexing>
    </replicated-cache>
```

A whole stack trace:

```java
     2021-06-10 19:41:27,993 ERROR [org.inf.sta.StateProviderImpl] (non-blocking-thread--p2-t1) ISPN000261: Failed to execute outbound transfer: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MarshallableUserObject marshaller not overridden in SerializationContext
        at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.unmarshall(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:248)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.unmarshall(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:237)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.getValue(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:81)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateProviderImpl.defaultMapEntryFromStore(StateProviderImpl.java:379)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:64)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableUsing$UsingSubscriber.onNext(FlowableUsing.java:104)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onNext(HalfSerializer.java:45)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FlowableConcatMap.java:204)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FlowableConcatMap.java:559)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.runAsync(FlowableObserveOn.java:402)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:176)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:322)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.runEager(ExecutorScheduler.java:287)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MarshallableUserObject marshaller not overridden in SerializationContext
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject.<init>(MarshallableUserObject.java:44)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.read(MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.java:49)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.read(MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.java:15)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.impl.ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.unmarshall(ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.java:32)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.readMessage(WrappedMessage.java:539)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.read(WrappedMessage.java:351)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.fromWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:129)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.unmarshall(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:246)
        ... 16 more
```

Anybody had the same issue?

Edit1:

Add IndexedEndpointEventModel definition:

```java
@Indexed
public class IndexedEndpointEventModel implements Serializable {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private String field1;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private LocalDateTime field2;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private LocalDateTime field3;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field4;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field5;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field6;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field7;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field8;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field9;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field10;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field11;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private Long field12;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private Integer field13;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private String field14;
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES, searchable = Searchable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, aggregable = Aggregable.NO)
    private Boolean field15;
    private String field16;
    private Map<String, List<String>> field17;
    private Map<String, List<String>> field18;

    public IndexedEndpointEventModel() {
        field1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field2 = LocalDateTime.now();
        field3 = LocalDateTime.now();
        field4 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field5 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field6 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field7 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field8 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field9 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field10 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field11 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field12 = RANDOM.nextLong();
        field13 = RANDOM.nextInt();
        field14 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field15 = RANDOM.nextBoolean();
        field16 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        field17 = Map.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        field18 = Map.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString()), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    }

// Setters/Getters

}
```

Edit2:

Additional exception stack trace (with await-initial-transfer="false"):

```
2021-06-11 21:29:57,973 ERROR [org.inf.int.imp.InvocationContextInterceptor] (non-blocking-thread--p2-t12) ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand on Cache 'event', writing keys [cc05c0d7-b984-485d-8afd-298743550a7b]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MarshallableUserObject marshaller not overridden in SerializationContext
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject.<init>(MarshallableUserObject.java:44)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.read(MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.java:49)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.read(MarshallableUserObject$___Marshaller_ff6b068168b51aac5d0c18c371e02ff55d3bb0cb73296e9cf1f4a65917105dec.java:15)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.impl.ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.unmarshall(ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.java:32)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.readMessage(WrappedMessage.java:539)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.read(WrappedMessage.java:351)
        at org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.fromWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:129)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:92)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore.unmarshall(RocksDBStore.java:524)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore.unmarshall(RocksDBStore.java:531)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore.putExpireDbData(RocksDBStore.java:1106)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore.addNewExpiry(RocksDBStore.java:551)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore.access$1200(RocksDBStore.java:82)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.rocksdb.RocksDBStore$RocksDBHandler.lambda$write$2(RocksDBStore.java:753)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean about "and one of the nodes freezes" ?

Comment: Could you share `IndexedEndpointEventModel` ?

Comment: @Diego Hi. I've added the model. I mean that node waits for when rebalancing's over and gets an exception after state transfer timeout. And what's interesting, if I use async state transfer (with await-initial-transfer=false), I get an exception all the time.